# Existence of Harmonic Spinors

Tags: spin-geometry

The harmonic spinor equation states that

$D \psi=0$,

where $D$ is a Dirac operator and $\psi$ is a spinor.  A spinor satisfying this equation is said to be harmonic.  Is there some result that one always define a harmonic spinor on a spin manifold when the appropriate Dirac operator is defined?  I make no other assumptions about the spinor.

Apologies if the question does not make sense, as I do not know anything about spin geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that every spin manifold has a non-zero harmonic spinor.

The Lichnerowicz formula for the Dirac operator $D$ is $D^2 = \nabla^*\nabla + \frac{1}{4}s$ where $s$ is the scalar curvature. It follows that if $M$ is a compact spin manifold with positive scalar curvature, then $M$ does not admit a non-zero harmonic spinor. To see this, let $\sigma$ be a harmonic spinor. As $s > 0$ and $M$ is compact, we have $s \geq 4c > 0$ for some constant $c$. Therefore, using the $L^2$ norm, we have

$$0 = \langle D^2\sigma, \sigma\rangle = \langle\nabla^*\nabla\sigma, \sigma\rangle + \langle\frac{1}{4}s\sigma, \sigma\rangle \geq \langle\nabla\sigma, \nabla\sigma\rangle + \langle c\sigma, \sigma\rangle = \|\nabla\sigma\|^2 + c\|\sigma\|^2.$$

As $\|\nabla\sigma\| \geq 0$, $\|\sigma\| \geq 0$, and $c > 0$, we see that $\sigma = 0$. Taking a little more care, the same conclusion holds if $s \geq 0$ but $s \not\equiv 0$.

For more details, see *Spin Geometry* by Lawson and Michelsohn, chapter II, section 8.

In the case that $s \equiv 0$, every harmonic spinor is parallel. The existence of a non-zero parallel spinor on a closed spin manifold $M$ places a significant restriction on its geometry. For instance, if $M$ is simply connected, either $M$ or $M\times S^1$ admits a Ricci-flat Kähler metric, see Theorem 1.2 of Hitchin's [*Harmonic Spinors*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870874900218).

Comment: Why is it that the $L^2$ norm of $D^2 \sigma$ and $\sigma$ is zero ie. why is it that the two are orthogonal?

Comment: As $\sigma$ is harmonic, $D\sigma = 0$.

Comment: Is there some simple way to test if a spin manifold has non-zero harmonic spinors by considering the kernel of the Dirac operator?

Comment: By the definition you gave in the question, a harmonic spinor is precisely an element in the kernel of the Dirac operator.